# Long custom filter name doesn't fit into layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, custom-filters

For the long enough custom filter name there is an issue with layout. Not too screaming in read-only mode but super obvious when edit mode is enabled. See an animated gif for details:

> [image: custom filters]

It seems that the limitation on name length has made on assumption that all letters have same width but they don't. Using the sequence of capital `W` shows the issue yet more clear.

Comment: Wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwhy would you name it that?

Comment: @Ollie I like double you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed and will go out after a merge and deploy. Thanks for reporting!

Also, might I suggest not naming your custom filter `wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww`

Comment: Or wait till the next build @SonictheK-DayHedgehog?

Comment: The issue is still there: current rev 2020.11.9.37970

Comment: That's because it hasn't been merged and deployed.

Comment: too perfect to pass code review phase?