# Long custom filter names don't fit into layout in questions tab

Tags: bug, design, custom-filters

Long custom filter names don't fit into layout.

Related to the old issue [Long custom filter name doesn't fit into layout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356314/long-custom-filter-name-doesnt-fit-into-layout)

But happening on the [questions tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions):

> [image: don't fit]